# Show information from database in jOptionPane

Tags: java, mysql

I have a quick question, im making a little program here for my schoolproject.
But now im stuck, im a beginning programmer in Java.

This is my written code:

```
int aantal = Integer.parseInt(jTextField1.getText());

    try {
        Connection conn = SimpleDataSourceV2.getConnection();

        Statement stat = conn.createStatement();

        ResultSet rs = stat.executeQuery("SELECT COUNT(id) FROM voedingswaarde WHERE kcal > " + aantal + ";");

        while (rs.next()) {
            "CODE"
        }
        rs.close();
        stat.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("Fout bij het laden aantal." + e);
    }
```

Im trying to print the result from the query (which is a value counted by the query) in a joptionpane messagedialogBox. So where i have "CODE" need to be replaced with a piece of code which prints it.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: [THIS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/retrieving.html) tutorial maybe help you

Answer (score 0):

```
JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(this, "Your Message", "Title of your Message", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null)
```

It depends on what information do you want do display on your JOptionPane...